# how to create redshift unload header row

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a unload query from redshift which provides the required data. I am looking to add a header row to the python script which will be written to each file. Thanks in advance.

Header row: should look exactly like this.
~id ~from ~to ~label starttime:Date endtime:Date accountid:String srcaddr:String dstaddr:String srcport:String dstport:String protocol:String packets:Int bytes:Int action:String

```
    def handler(event, context):
        now   = datetime.utcnow().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
        past  = now - timedelta(minutes=120)

        cmd = """unload (SELECT 'pk' AS id,
        'version' AS version,
        'accountid' AS accountid,
        'interfaceid' AS interfaceid,
        'srcaddr' AS srcaddr,
        'dstaddr' AS dstaddr,
        'srcport' AS srcport,
        'dstport' AS dstport,
        'protocol' AS protocol,
        'packets' AS packets,
        'bytes' AS bytes,
        'starttime' AS startime,
        'endtime' AS endtime,
        'action' AS action,
        'logstatus' AS logstatus,
        'fromeni' AS fromeni,
        'toeni' AS toeni
    UNION ALL SELECT
        cast(pk AS varchar(255)) AS id,
        cast(version AS varchar(255)) AS version,
        cast(accountid AS varchar(255)) AS accountid,
        cast(interfaceid AS varchar(255)) AS interfaceid,
        cast(srcaddr AS varchar(255)) AS srcaddr,
        cast(dstaddr AS varchar(255)) AS dstaddr,
        cast(srcport AS varchar(255)) AS srcport,
        cast(dstport AS varchar(255)) AS dstport,
        cast(protocol AS varchar(255)) AS protocol,
        cast(packets AS varchar(255)) AS packets,
        cast(bytes AS varchar(255)) AS bytes,
        cast(starttime AS varchar(255)) AS starttime,
        cast(endtime AS varchar(255)) AS endtime,
        action,
        logstatus,
        cast(fromeni AS varchar(255)) AS fromeni,
        cast(toeni AS varchar(255)) AS toeni
    FROM dimension.vpc_flow_logs)\
            to 's3://xxxxxxxxxx/' \
            iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/task' \
            delimiter as ',' \
            PARALLEL OFF \
            ESCAPE \
            manifest allowoverwrite"""

        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(cmd)
            conn.commit()
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        handler({},{})
```

Comment: One option would be to use `UNION ALL` where you explicitly select the names of the columns and then union your actual data.

Comment: updated to what i have now. im seeing this error when running the python script 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unload.py", line 80, in <module>
    handler({},{})
  File "unload.py", line 73, in handler
    cursor.execute(cmd)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: unload (SELECT 'pk' AS id,

Comment: Hmm I don't have a redshift cluster handy to play around on but maybe you have to escape your quotes using "\"?

Comment: I don't think you can do this from redshift, because it splits the file out based upon the parameter that you provide.there would need to be an option (which there isnt). The union all solution will only append to the first file not subsequent.

Comment: By using the `parallel off` parameter, you can write to only 1 file. Not ideal in all cases, but this is a solution I've used a handful of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! As of Oct 2 2018, Redshift started to roll out support for `HEADER` option in the `UNLOAD` command which will export the column titles as the header of your csv.

Here is their announcement:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=6136

Doc's have been updated as well:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

e.g.

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM customers')
TO 's3://<bucket-name>/customers.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::<IAM_USER_ID#>:role/myRedshiftRole'
PARALLEL OFF DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

I just tried it on a db with 100-300 columns, works a treat. Gone are the days of `UNION` column definitions! Saves SOO much time for any data scientists out there using Redshift and need to export data for third party platforms!

Also works with the default `PARALLEL ON` with multiple output files.